# Restricted mean survival time meta-analysis

Tags: r

I want to conduct a meta-analysis of single means. However, these means are restricted mean survival time (RMST) of cerebrospinal fluid shunt inserted to treat hydrocephalus.

For this, I have digitized published survival curves with https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/.
Then I have extracted the individual patient data with the R package IPDfromKM.
Finaly, I have recontructed the survival curve and calculated the RMST at 12 months as decribed here: [How to compute the mean survival time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173044/how-to-compute-the-mean-survival-time).

I have yet the following RMST and associated standard error.

```
study <- c("study1", "study2", "study3", "study4", "study5")
n_patients <- c(535, 209, 111, 599, 434)
rmst_12 <- c(10.54759, 11.36175, 10.50244, 10.51183, 8.716552)
se_12 <- c(0.1463532, 0.1439506, 0.3246873, 0.1471398, 0.2374582)


> data
   study n_patients  rmst_12     se_12
1 study1        535 10.54759 0.1463532
2 study2        209 11.36175 0.1439506
3 study3        111 10.50244 0.3246873
4 study4        599 10.51183 0.1471398
5 study5        434 8.716552 0.2374582
```

Now I am performing the meta-analysis of my RMST.

```
# Compute standard deviation (SD) from standard error (SE) ----
data $ sd_12 <- data $ se_12 * sqrt (data $ n_patients)

# Download useful package
require (meta)

# Compute the meta-analysis with the metamean function ----
mm_12 <- metamean (n = n_shunts,
                mean = rmst_12,
                sd = sd_12,
                studlab = author_year, 
                data = data, 
                method.mean = "Luo",
                method.sd = "Shi",
                sm = 'MRAW',             
                random = TRUE,          
                warn = TRUE,
                prediction = TRUE,
                method.tau = "REML")

 > mm_12
Number of studies combined: k = 5
Number of observations: o = 1888

                        mean             95%-CI
Common effect model  10.5757 [10.4247; 10.7268]
Random effects model 10.3373 [ 9.4868; 11.1878]
Prediction interval          [ 7.0212; 13.6534]

Quantifying heterogeneity:
 tau^2 = 0.8975 [0.2937; 7.7528]; tau = 0.9474 [0.5419; 2.7844]
 I^2 = 95.6% [92.3%; 97.5%]; H = 4.78 [3.61; 6.34]

Test of heterogeneity:
     Q d.f.  p-value
 91.39    4 < 0.0001

Details on meta-analytical method:
- Inverse variance method
- Restricted maximum-likelihood estimator for tau^2
- Q-Profile method for confidence interval of tau^2 and tau
- Prediction interval based on t-distribution (df = 3)
- Untransformed (raw) means
```

Everything works fine but, I am wondering myself if this is correct and right from a methodological point of view ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS. I am unsure if it is the right place for this post.

Charles

Comment: I think you must search for it in stats.stackexchange.com